# Log4j Configuration: How to append multiple log4j conf in 1 xml file?

Tags: xml, log4j

I am trying to make a common log4j.xml file for multiple application. The point is, some package paths are the same(Even class names) in different applications so I can't define it like:

```
log4j.logger.com.aaa.bbb=debug, logfile
```

How can I separate this log files according to the applications? I can do it in class files using the appender name in logger like this:

```
private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("CAppender");
```

But I do not want to change the code inside classes.

Any ideas?